# Firebird INDEX Expression for CONTAINING text. Is it possible?

Tags: firebird

For Firebird 2.5 and Firebird 3.0

Is it possible to create an index for a CONTAINING condition?

Example:

```
select id, name
from tableXYC
where name containing :text
```

Comment: Full-text-search - if you don't know the term -  is a large problem of it's own kind. There were 3rd party projects that bind Firebird with something like Lucene to produce FTS-capable Firebird-derived databases, google around.

Comment: Term Full-text-search is not mentioned in the Firebird documentation, which is why I didn't use it here. 
My intention was to ask a short question with keywords: Predicates CONTAINING and INDEX Expression.
I believe that anyone who tries to solve this problem or get more information will try searching for these keywords.

I know this is not possible from some old documentation.. I was trying to find a solution with Expression and for a moment I thought that someone had managed to "trick" the firebird.
Thanks for the feedback and recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to create such index inside Firebird 2.5/3.0.

Comment: Yes, I have seen in the documentation that this is not possible. However, I wanted to check if anyone had managed to do it in any way (eg with expression).
Thanks for your reply

Comment: I also cannot imagine how this should work but wonder why docs say "When CONTAINING is used in the search conditions of DML queries, the Firebird optimizer can use an index on the searched column, if a suitable one exists."